# How to add an item to a cached collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, viewstate

I would like to cache a collection in the viewstate, but I wonder if there is a better way to add an item to this collection!

```
private List<MyClass> CachedItems
{
    get { return (List<MyClass>)ViewState["CachedItems"]; }
    set { ViewState["CachedItems"] = value; }
}

private void AddToCachedItems(MyClass item)
{
    CachedItems = CachedItems.Concat(new[] { item }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<MyClass> CachedItems
{
    get
    {
        return (List<MyClass>)( ViewState["CachedItems"] = ViewState["CachedItems"] ??
                new List<MyClass>());

    }
}
```

Then just

```
CachedItems.Add(new MyClass());
```